# How to calculate the area and volume of a gömböc?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

[image]What are the correct formulas for calculating the area and the volume of the gömböc, if any have developed them? If there are none, could you help creating them?

The gömböc is a neat convex three-dimensional homogeneous body which, when resting on a flat surface, has just one stable and one unstable point of equilibrium that corrects itself if tipped over. (From Wikipedia).

"Reference": [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gömböc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6mb%C3%B6c)

Comment: In case you know much about gömböcs, it would be good to add a brief explanation or reference for if and why a gömböc is *unique* up to a homothety. (I'm not saying I was sure it is.)

Comment: Calculating them as a function of what?

Comment: @peterheinig:  it is in fact not unique up to homothety.

Comment: Importantly, of course, the plural is gömböcök. ;)

Comment: And thanks to @Billy, I feel free to pedanticize by pointing out that just as the French word démocratie is englished to democracy, the French word homothétie is properly englished to homothecy. (In both French words, the t is pronounced as an s.)

Comment: @Lubin an even better example to this inconsistency than the word "democracy", where '...tie' is turned into '...cy'  might be the pair "prophétie"-"prophecy", where '...hétie' is turned into '...hecy'.

Comment: The origin of the words is Greek, not French.

Comment: Analogy is definitely **not** a valid principle in linguistics.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is not a unique gömböc up to orientation and scaling so the question asked in the body about the volume and area of "the" gömböc is underspecified. You might try to improve the question by specifying one particular gömböc that you're interested in, but then, as you probably know, the area and volume of any solid body can be computed by integration, rarely have closed form evaluations, so I doubt that you will find formulas better than these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element